# Show view for different Users types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am planning an application with a User model + different User subtypes (such as Students, Teachers, ...) with a dedicated model for each.
I am planning to authenticate on Users level directly in rails, with no specific gem.

My problem is about handling the Users Show view file:

- should I show the users directly in the Show file of the User
  controller (adding a lot of conditions in my view file, depending of
  the User subtype) or
- should I use the User show controller action as    a gateway
  redirecting the a controller dedicated to each subtype, ...then having a
  more straightforward show view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should be almost free of that kind of logic. That would break MVC and lower the maintainability of the app. You should at least leave that to the controller, something like:

```
def show
  render proper_view_by_user
end

private
def proper_view_by_user
   # Define this user_type on your own
   # on devise you'd do something like current_user.class_name
   switch user_type
     when 'Admin' then
       'admins_show' # template found  in your views folder
     when 'NormalUser' then
       'normal_show'
     else
       'normal_show'
   end

end
```

Unless this a learning project, really consider using devise and not rolling your own auth system. Read [this](https://blog.codeship.com/why-you-shouldnt-roll-your-own-authentication/).

Comment: Thanks, this does seem right not to overload the view file too much. Your code seems to redirect me to the dedicated subtype controller show action, if i am not mistaken. I am still a bit confused with all the rolling thing: is the rolling only about authing, or does it scope to the entire website structure and operation. I will read the article you mention and will try to learn a bit about it.

Comment: I meant the auth part Mainly, because it is sensitive and hard to cover all fronts. Devise gem has a lot of features and has reasonable security as far as I know, and it also has a ton of documentation and answers on SO to guide you. Can can gem also has a few more features that would help you with authorizing parts of the app to different users, but you can code them on your own just fine. Give it a thought!

Comment: I am not familiar with Authorization concept but it will come. As I thought I could do this inside my controllers just fine and discriminate depending of the authicated user... One last question though: Do you think I should keep a User model + submodels ? Or should I just get rid of the Users model and add authentication details (emails, password..) to the Submodels (which then are no longer submodels but more different types of users..)

Comment: If you added password and auth fields for each submodel those fields start repeating themselves and In my opinion it makes the code a little less DRY. One simple way to model types of users is using a belongs_to polymorphic association, you'd have in your user model with auth fields something like `belongs_to :pointed, :polymorphic => true` and in and admin model for example `has_one :user, as: :pointed`. Read on polymorphic associations here: https://launchschool.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails. Note how you need two fields on the migration for users.

Comment: I understand. I have all my different models (admin, teacher, student, ..) and they all own a User through a polymorphic association. User will only carry email, password, and category of user (Student, teacher.) so that I can call the appropriate parent/child

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to use partials, and then render the partial that has the same name as the user subtype:

```
<%# users/show.html.erb %>
<%= render partial: user.user_subtype %>

<%# users/_admin.html.erb %>
<h1>Admin</h1>

<%# users/_student.html.erb %>
<h1>Student</h1>

<%# users/_teacher.html.erb %>
<h1>Teacher</h1>
```

As an aside, if you're dealing with access levels I would highly recommend using the [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) gem. It will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the partials do make a cleaner view file. Yet another answer suggest I shouldn't add too much logic in the view file. I am still a bit confused but need to read a bit about Devise I guess

Comment: You probably won't find much about this in the Devise documentation, since Devise is mainly concerned with authentication. What you're doing is *authorization*, which is concerned with what the user can do after they've signed in. As I mentioned, check out the Pundit gem - it is very helpful in removing authorization logic from the views.